# Wordpress Block Theme Query Data

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-lightsail

I have been using the Twenty Twenty-Two theme in WordPress that is running on AWS lightsail multisite WP environment.  I have found it easy enough to layout content using block editor.

Now I want to query data from the database (for now just want to use the WordPress database where I added a table) and display that information.

I see tutorials for older versions of WP but I can not find any resource that provide much guidance on this. What I know thus far is I can not simply add php code to a page or post.

Comment: Can you share what your tried?

Comment: @vadivela I have tried to add php code to both pages and posts.  They don't seem to be php pages though and just render as text, so I am quite lost.

Such as:
<?php
echo "Hello world!<br>";
?>

Comment: I can't help without demo or login

Comment: @vadivela I am not sure what you want me to demo.  I don't know where you can add custom php code in block editor therefore I have nothing to show you.

Comment: Can you create shortcode and use in editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question of "[how to] simply add php code to a page or post [in WordPress]" is not easy to answer because there are multiple ways you might approach it.

I recommend you search for phrases like

- "[add php WordPress functions.php](https://wpmudev.com/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-functions-php/)"
- "Why [Child Theme custom php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49119/where-to-put-custom-php-files-in-a-child-theme) WordPress"
- "how-to simple WordPress [plugin custom php](https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/creating-wordpress-plugin-easier-think/)"

Good luck!